# Zabbix not plotting values from a simple text file on another host using Zabbix agent

Tags: network-monitoring, resource-usage, zabbix

I have Zabbix server installed in a Ubuntu virtual machine (hyper-visor is VMware Workstation Pro 15). My goal is to monitor a text file containing floating point numbers (the numbers are written in a text file after completion of some simulation). This text file resides on my Windows machine. I have installed Zabbix agent on Windows and I am monitoring resources of my Windows machine successfully from Zabbix front end in browser. But upon adding an item to read log file, the graph does not show anything. I am using Zabbix agent (active) and my key is:

**log[c:\Agent\Try.log,,,,skip,,]**

Type of information is float. Does any one know that why values aren't getting plotted?

Contents of log file:

7.7

4.8

7.7

5.9

1.3

6.8

Zabbix server's IP address: **192.168.19.128**

Windows machine's IP address: **192.168.0.13**

Windows agent's configuration file changed parameters:

LogFile=**c:\Agent\zabbix_agentd.log**

Server=**192.168.0.13,127.0.0.1**

ServerActive=**192.168.0.13,127.0.0.1**

Hostname=**FQDN from system properties**

Answer (score 0):

Is the item getting any data? If not, check the following.

- Can the agent connect to server on port 10051 (default)?
- Do host name and "Hostname" parameter in the agent config file match (they are case sensitive)?
- Any errors in the agent and server logfiles?
- Is that file having new values added periodically? The `skip` parameter will only pick up new values.

The [troubleshooting page](https://zabbix.org/wiki/Troubleshooting#Zabbix_says_.22Agent_unreachable.22.2C_but_the_host_is_up._How_do_I_debug_that.3F) can provide further hints if the above all looks correct.

Comment: Yes agent connects to server on default port as I can see CPU usage etc. of Windows machine in front end. Host name matches with FQDN on Windows machine. Error in agent's log is 9392:20190814:132510.203 active check configuration update from [192.168.0.13:10051] started to fail (cannot connect to [[192.168.0.13]:10051]: Connection refused.)

Comment: New values are added periodically

Comment: The error message should help you to fix it. Agent is unable to connect to the server port. Note that FQDN does not matter directly, the value in the agent configuration file does.

Comment: What could be the causes of agent being unable to connect to the server port? I have already added inbound and outbound rules in Windows firewall to open port number 10050 and 10051. What else is needed to be done?

Comment: It would be a lot of guesswork to answer that. Incorrect server address in the agent config, incorrect DNS, server not running, local firewall on the server, network firewall, routing issues and other things. You'll have to test connectivity to the TCP port, perhaps with a telnet client, and work on it until that works - nobody can say for sure what is the cause for you.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, Zabbix server is successfully monitoring resources like CPU usage, free disk space, network usage etc. of the Windows machine on which text file is present. So most of the things which you mentioned in your comment aren't the problems here! E.g. if server address was incorrect in agent config, how is Windows machine getting monitored properly? Same goes for incorrect DNS, server not running and routing issues. As far as firewall is considered, my previous comment states that relevant ports have been opened in firewall. Pinging both servers succeeds as well.

Comment: Those working items are of the passive type.